# Is there any Gradle eclipse IDE integration?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin, integration, gradle

i'm looking for an eclipse ide integration for gradle. 
I've installed the gradle editor from
http://www.breskeby.com/downloads/gradle/eclipse/update/

But this is far away from what i expect from an ide integration. 
It provides only some syntax highlighting. 
No auto completion, error mark, task list, etc.

Is there any real ide integration for eclipse?

Comment: faced the same issue: breskeby plugin doesn't add gradle dependencies to project classpath ( Reading the answers - is there only way to migrate to STS IDE or install full STS support to your eclipse?

Comment: I neither use one of the current gradle IDE integrations because there is no additional value. 
Generate the eclipse project files `.project` and `.classpath` 
using the gradle eclipse plugin `apply plugin: 'eclipse'`. Invoke `gradle eclipse` from the command line console. This will add the required dependencies.

Comment: in this case do you have to `gradle eclipse` each time after your dependencies change? Won't it override your eclipse project settings to default?

Comment: Yes i'll do it each time. If there is something specific needed, you could configure it in your gradle build file. I do also not check in the eclipse project files into version control system. In that way you assure that every development team member is using the same eclipse project settings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SpringSource Tool Suite includes Gradle support.

See http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/2.7.0.M1/reference/html/gradle/faq.html for some information, though it is a bit out-of-date. Better support was added in STS 2.8.0.

http://www.springsource.com/landing/best-development-tool-enterprise-java for downloading STS.

You can install STS into your Eclipse installation and Gradle support along with it, if you don't want to start from the STS release.

Comment: That is far the same as the one on http://www.breskeby.com
It is very disappointing that there is nothing better.

Comment: Are you sure? Is the plugin the one you see here? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1koQ2V920qE STS has a different one. It isn't perfect, but it's not bad at all, similar in approach to the m2e plugin (maven support).

Comment: Yes, i mean that one. I've tried it again. STS 2.8.1 and also directly update into eclipse indigo.

Comment: The plugin in the video above is not STS gradle support.

Comment: Yes, it is the one from http://www.breskeby.com.
The task list is only available on run configuration. It does not have a useful auto completion. You cannot configure your own version of gradle. You must use the elder version 1.0-milestone-3...

Answer (score 13):

Looks like the STS team extracted the plugin into stand alone module
https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle/

Answer (score 5):

Nodeclipse also has [Gradle for Eclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle) that runs gradle. That lets use gradle with any project (Java, Maven, C++, Android)

There is also [Minimalist Editor](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/editors/gradle) for `.gradle` files

[image]

This can be used where [Pivotal (former SpringSource) Gradle IDE](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/) can't be used yet.

Both can be installed together via [Gradle IDE Pack](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-ide-pack/)

Answer (score 3):

The Buildship project from Gradleware provides great Eclipse integration. See https://github.com/eclipse/buildship for its homepage and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html for an introduction.

Comment: The Buildship [is replacing the STS plug-in](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/wiki/Migration-guide-from-STS-Gradle-to-Buildship). I am moving from STS Gradle to Buildship.